# how to use tools:openDrawer = "bottom"

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout, drawer, mmdrawercontroller

I want to open my Drawer at the bottom but i could not is there any one who could solve my issue???

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:openDrawer="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
```

Comment: see https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

Comment: Does it work if you try the namespace `app`? As in `app:openDrawer="bottom"`

Comment: the `tools` name-space would set it for the XML preview ...

Comment: hey @MartinZeitler i also set the behaviour in java file mColorPalletDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.BOTTOM);

Comment: namespace app isn't working for me

Answer (score 2):

`DrawerLayout` can't be use from bottom or up it's only for vertical sides(left, right) for bottom you need to use `BottomSheetDialogFragment` or `BottomSheetBehavior`